# Javascript multidimensional array question

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

On this simple example (https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3xn7dr7jc) :

```
var arrayButton = new Array(11);
var arrayAdvancedButtons = new Array(6);

for(let i=0; i < arrayButton.length; i++){
    
    arrayButton[i] = [i, 0];
}


for(let i=0; i < arrayAdvancedButtons.length; i++){
    
    arrayAdvancedButtons[i] = arrayButton;
}

 arrayAdvancedButtons[0][0][1] += 1;


console.log(arrayAdvancedButtons);
```

With this declaration :

```
arrayAdvancedButtons[0][0][1] += 1;
```

All the the array elements in this position **[x][0][1]** are incremented instead of **[0][0][1]** element.

What is the reason of this result?

Comment: all of the elements of `arrayAdvancedButtons` are references to the same `arrayButton` array.

Comment: `arrayButton` is one single array which you assign to multiple slots in `arrayAdvancedButtons`. Modifying "one" of the arrays modifies "all" arrays. The quotes are because there is literally just one array you can manipulate from multiple places.